# Can't install Ubuntu 22.04 package named "fonts-noto-color-emoji" using apt

Tags: package-management, fonts

I deleted this package trying to change default emoji font and now I want to reinstall it.

The package can be found here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/fonts-noto-color-emoji

When trying  to `sudo apt install fonts-noto-color-emoji` I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package fonts-noto-color-emoji is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'fonts-noto-color-emoji' has no installation candidate
```

What does it mean and how can I reinstall the package?

**Edit 1:**

Regarding third-party PPAs, running

```
grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/ | sed -re 's/^\/etc\/apt\/sources\.list((\.d\/)?|(:)?)//' -e 's/(.*\.list):/\[\1\] /' -e 's/deb http:\/\/ppa.launchpad.net\/(.*?)\/ubuntu .*/ppa:\1/'
```

returned

```
[vscode.list] deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf] http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main
[mozillateam-ubuntu-ppa-jammy.list] deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu/ jammy main
[google-chrome.list] deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
[teams.list] deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable main
[obsproject-ubuntu-obs-studio-jammy.list] deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu/ jammy main
[signal-xenial.list] deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/signal-desktop-keyring.gpg] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy restricted
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates restricted
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```

**Edit 2:**

The result of `apt-cache policy fonts-noto-color-emoji` is

```
fonts-noto-color-emoji:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: This is a standard, canonical curated package so something strange must be ongoing with your package management. Did you add third party PPA's?

Comment: I updated my original question with a list of the added third-party PPAs.

Comment: Nothing (really) suspect to be seen. No warnings or else in the output of "sudo apt update"? What is the output of "apt-cache policy fonts-noto-color-emoji"?

Comment: I just  ran sudo apt update without the slightest warning or error.

Comment: What is the output of "apt-cache policy fonts-noto-color-emoji"?

Comment: If all you are after are colour Emotes why not just install `Emote` from `Ubuntu Software` as I have done in 22.04?  `Ctrl Alt e` brings up the list.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks for your comment, I added the result to the original question.

Comment: I suggest you temporary try to change your software server. It is not normal that no package is available, and could be a (temporary) problem with your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem: for some reason the first option  "Cannonical-supported free and open-source software (main) was unticked in Software & Updates:

[image]

I enabled the option and now everything works as it should.

My question now is how this option got unticked in the first place, since I did a clean install less than a week ago and I never unticked it myself.